# Inline CSS styles in JSP

Tags: css, jsp, inline-styles

I am trying to render [*THIS*](http://jsfiddle.net/4eL39sm1/3/) in JSP. I want the styling to be inline right now as I am in the early stages of development .

My JSP code is

```
<%
%><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %><%
%><%

<style type="text/css">
.line {
width:70%;
}
.line:after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: 8px;
left: 45%;
}
.line:before {
content:'';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 15px 0;
border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: 9px;
left: 45%;
}
</style>
<%@include file="/apps//global.jsp"%>
<hr class="line">
%>
```

I am certain the css styling is fince as it renders correctly in fiddle.

Is there a way I can fix this? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks much.

Answer (score -1):

for each and every section define classes for css and include it in  using